# Error sending notification webhook: 503 in Ansible AWX

Tags: ansible-awx

In AWX 21.0.0, when I set a notification Webhook to a target API and I test it, I got the following message:

*Error sending notification webhook: 503*

If, from the AWX server I try to call the same external URL with curl, I got a response without issue.

After some logs search, we found these:

> Blockquote
> 2022-12-19 08:42:27,917 ERROR    [b38e3ee645b5457b8e726338581efb81] awx.main.notifications.webhook_backend Error sending notification webhook: 503
> 2022-12-19 08:42:27,919 ERROR    [b38e3ee645b5457b8e726338581efb81] awx.main.tasks.system Send Notification Failed Error sending notification webhook: 503
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/awx/main/tasks/system.py", line 293, in send_notifications
> sent = notification.notification_template.send(notification.subject, notification.body)
> File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/awx/main/models/notifications.py", line 185, in send
> return backend_obj.send_messages([notification_obj])
> File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/awx/main/notifications/webhook_backend.py", line 81, in send_messages
> raise Exception(smart_str(_("Error sending notification webhook: {}").format(r.status_code)))
> Exception: Error sending notification webhook: 503

It doesn't help us much, but at least, we got some logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it was because a proxy configured in AWX. Excluding the target from using that proxy make it work.